# PS/SBAS Processing of S1 in Envi Sarscape 5.2

Tags: envi, sentinel-1, sbas

I'm processing a stack of s1a images in PS. I am now running the inversion first step.

In the progress bar, it is stuck at the 'preliminary candidates selection' for quite some time. I am not sure if the process has crashed or is it just taking a long time to process.

Anyone knows if this is normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem has been solved. the issue is regarding envi's handling of S1 images.